# How do I open a csv file, read the file line by line, base64_decode() it and write the decoded data to a new file?

Tags: php, html, csv, base64

I want to be able to read a csv file, decode it with PHP base64_decode() and then write that decoded data to a new file in the same format.

I tried reading the file line by line and then decoding it while it read the file but the data kept coming out corrupt or broken (containing symbols and random characters).

My csv file has only one column of base64 encoded strings with no delimiters. Each string is on its own row and there is only one string per row.

Like so:

```
ZXhhbXBsZUBlbWFpbC5jb20=
ZXhhbXBsZUBlbWFpbC5jb20=
ZXhhbXBsZUBlbWFpbC5jb20=
ZXhhbXBsZUBlbWFpbC5jb20=
etc...
```

I want my new file to be in the same format and the same data but it should be decoded.

like so:

```
example@email.com
example@email.com
example@email.com
example@email.com
etc...
```

This is how I am reading the data. I tried using trim() inside base64_decode to get rid of any possible white space or characters but it didn't help. I haven't got to the write to csv part yet because I need proper output.

```
// csv file is uploaded via a form, I move it to the uploads/ directory
$csv_file = $_FILES['file']['name'];

// filename will always be the user uploaded file
$file_name = $csv_file;

// open the file in read
if (($handle = fopen("uploads/".$file_name, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    // read the file line by line
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // display column of data
        echo base64_decode($data[0]);

    }
    // close file
    fclose($handle);
}
```

My expected output:

```
example@email.com
example@email.com
example@email.com
example@email.com
etc...
```

My actual output:

```
�XZ�˘��A͡����չ兡��������X\�\�[�\�PXZ�˘��\�\��YM�XZ�˘��G7FWfV�g&GF������6��email@example.com�]�[�ܙ[�XZ�˘��G6ӓ���#T�����6��#7C7##4�����6��ɽ���Ѽ��������兡��������ٜ̌LPXZ�˘��Aɕ�����������email@examplevV�W'6��CCT�����6��v�G7W���d�����6��v���v��&W$�����6��ݥ�����齝兡������wwwemail@exampleemail@exampleۙ�\�MLMP[����]]��NNۚ�XZ�˘��Aщɽݸ������兡������[٘[M�[����Aѡ������͕�٥���
�������ѡ����ѽ�������������[YX���ܝ
```

Comment: Isn't this like the 2nd/3rd time you post something like this?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to word it in a way someone would understand, I deleted those posts because they got put on hold and then set as duplicate. Haven't got any help on the issue. I also attempted with shell commands the first two times and this time I'm using fopen and fgetcsv. I wouldn't post about it again but I'm not sure why it's not working and haven't gotten help for it.

Comment: what does `var_dump($data)` give?

Comment: ```var_dump($data[0])``` gives me the column of base64 encoded strings line by line from my csv file but it begins with: ```string(121167) "``` and ends in a closing ```"```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working...just needed to auto-detect line endings.

```
// without this my code breaks, I'm assuming since my csv has no delimiter it was having issues finding the line endings
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);
// Store each row in this array
$allRowsAsArray = array();
// open file
if (!$fp=fopen("uploads/".$csv_file,"r")) echo "The file could not be opened.<br/>";

// add each row from col into array
while (( $data = fgetcsv ( $fp , 0)) !== FALSE ) 
{
    $allRowsAsArray[] = $data;
}

// decode array line by line, also add linebreaks back in
foreach($allRowsAsArray as $result) {
    echo base64_decode($result[0])."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = new SplFileObject("data.csv");
while (!$file->eof()) {
    echo base64_decode($file->fgetcsv());
}
```

Comment: $file->fgetcsv() is an array. base64_decode will shoot an error because it expects a string. This won't work, unfortunately.